# Where do I get the villagers to start off an iron farm

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am building an iron farm and have almost completed it, when it struck me!
Where do I get the villagers from?
The simple answer is, go off and find a village, but I don't really want to be wandering around for miles looking for a village, then have to take them back by some means.

What I was wandering was, is there an easier way?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just wait around at night time for [Zombie Villagers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie#Zombie_Villager). Then cure them.  You need to find two to get a breeding pair.

So you need

- two splash [potions of weakness](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potion#Potion_of_Weakness)

  - 2 bottles
  - water
  - netherwart
  - [fermented spider eye](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fermented_Spider_Eye)

    - brown mushroom
    - spider eye
    - sugar
  - gunpowder
- two [golden apples](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Golden_Apple)

  - 2 regular apples plus 18 bars of gold
- patience to wait around at night long enough to find zombie villagers

Once you find a zombie villager, you will want to trap him in a cage and put a roof over him, so he doesn't die before he is done being cured.  Once he is trapped hit him with the weakness potion, wait, and make sure that you hit me by the potion effect animation.  Then feed him the golden apple.  Then wait.

Since you have to be out at night you need a nice open area where monsters can spawn.  You will probably also need some equipment to kill the mobs you aren't interested in. With a little luck you can usually corral a couple in 2-3 night cycles.

Comment: that is genius.

Comment: You could also use a zombie spawner with this method to get higher rates faster.

Comment: @Aze, certainly, you just have to be lucky enough to have one close to where you want to build your new village/iron farm.

Comment: @Zoredache or move it there using silk touch?

Comment: AFAIK silk touch cannot pick up mob spawners, unless something has changed in the latest version?

Comment: Should be nuggets, not bars?

Comment: @imulsion Two kinds of golden apples now, one with nuggets and one with bars. Curing zombie villagers needs the one with bars.

Comment: With 1.6+ you have a golden apple made with bars, and a 'enchanted golden apple' (aka 'notch apple') made with golden blocks.  You could only use nuggets between 1.3-1.5.  Curing a zombie in 1.6+ takes an apple surrounded by golden bars.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie We learn something new every day I suppose xD