# How do I get villagers in my world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is it possible to get villagers in my survival world? I can get villagers on my creative world, but not on survival mode.

Comment: I am not a PE player.  Can you cure zombies on PE?  Like this?  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/164145/where-do-i-get-the-villagers-to-start-off-an-iron-farm/164158#164158

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to find villagers. They can be found in villages generated when you start a new world.

Villages were added as of version [0.9.0 build 1](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_version_history/Development_versions#A1):

> Added villages. They spawn with gravel, wooden or sandstone bridges.

As for villagers, they were also added in [0.9.0 build 1](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_version_history/Development_versions#A1):

> Added villagers. Same level of AI as PC version 1.0.0 - They cannot trade, breed or open doors.

Here is a screenshot of a village in Minecraft: Pocket Edition:

[image]

You will find villagers walking around, and as of version [0.9.0 build 2](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_version_history/Development_versions#A2), they have sounds!

Comment: So u have to build the village

Comment: No, villages are randomly generated when you start a new world.

Comment: Ok I get it is there a seed for it

Comment: Try the seed "1439131969" without the quotation marks. If I answered your question, please accept this as the answer!

Comment: Wow, I might delete my answer. Once again outdone by the mighty Caleb. Nice job!

Comment: Is it on old flat or the other one

Comment: I think it will work in either the "old" or "infinite" world type. However "Superflat" will not work.

Comment: Survival or creative?

Comment: Either, they both generate the same world

Comment: This is just me noticing strange things, but all of the trees in this picture are old trees except the one in the middle of the village.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its a birch tree.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find a village. Villages look something like this. [image]

Comment: Do I have to build it

Comment: Is it there the second you spawn

Comment: @user82545 Nope, villages are randomly generated. You have to find one.

Comment: What is the seed for one can I get it on pocket addition 0.9.0?

Comment: @user82545 Please look that up yourself...