# What can I do to populate an empty village?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I’m playing unmodded Minecraft on the xbox 360, in survival mode. I have explored the entire map, and found 1 village. The last villager died. What can I do to get villagers back?

Comment: Basically the same answer as http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/164145/where-do-i-get-the-villagers-to-start-off-an-iron-farm/164158#164158  So, cure zombies.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/164145/where-do-i-get-the-villagers-to-start-off-an-iron-farm?lq=1

Comment: It's not the same. OP asks how to repopulate, not build from scratch. If that another question was an aswer it would mean that village will repopulate on its own, but wiki and answers here says it's not. This question needs the correct answer and explanation.

Answer (score 6):

My memory has faded a lot since 1.7 (PC) but I recall you being able to throw a splash potion of weakness at a zombie villager then use a golden apple (Not enchanted golden apple) on the zombie straight afterwards and give it 2-5 mins to be converted to a villager.

Be sure to keep it away from other zombies for obvious reasons.

More info and evidence can be found [here](https://www.digminecraft.com/getting_started/how_to_cure_zombie_villager.php)

Answer (score 0):

It increase the village population, you must make village houses. A simple way to make a village house is a door and a block next to it. The systems trys to detect if it's a house or not. If the system detects it as a house, then a villager appears. You can make a lot of houses and you can make the population grow. You need to have 2 houses in order for villagers to breed.

Example of a house needed to increase population:

[image: VILLAGEPOPULATION]

Video example of making a population:

**Update:** Since you have no villagers, try to find a zombie villager and cure it by:

1. Trapping it.
2. Throwing a Splash Potion of Weakness
3. Feed it a Golden Apple.
4. Wait until it turns into a normal villager.
5. Try to push it al the way to where your village spawner is you know the village houses in the picture at the top.
6. You will need 2 villagers to start breeding, so repeat the steps above and you should have an infinite amount of villagers.

Comment: He's not looking to create Iron Golems.

Comment: @aytimothy Okay I deleted that part of the answer.

Comment: Also, please explain what the video is trying to convey (in case it goes offline) and the OP is not looking to start from a few villagers, **he is looking to start from ZERO villagers** and you can't get a villager to spawn with the method you've described; only stimulate the breeding of villagers.

Comment: This answer didn't work for you. Why did you change your vote.

Comment: @aytimothy I got an idea of curing zombie villagers which should work.